# Error "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required" when installing package

Tags: python-3.7

When I am installing a Python package e.g. `musicplayer` I am getting an error like this:

```
Collecting musicplayer
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e2/7a1890044c7cb2073b83924b5868eea55207317c12092d9615869381dc7e/musicplayer-1.20141030.091600.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: musicplayer
  Running setup.py install for musicplayer: started
    Running setup.py install for musicplayer: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bhanu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\musicplayer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0xj1qlt5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'musicplayer' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bhanu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\musicplayer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0xj1qlt5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\musicplayer\
```